# Prediction error in xgboost R while combining caret

Tags: r, xgboost, predict

I created an xgboost model on R using the xgboost package which I was able to train and test successfully. However, when I tried to predict using the model and the variables listed in the variable importance, I kept getting this error

> " Error in predict.xgb.Booster(xgb_model$finalModel, x_pred) :
> Feature names stored in `object` and `newdata` are different!"

I have checked the names of the variables used in the building of the model and they are exactly the same as those used in the prediction. Do I need to use the exact variables used in the model building for the prediction?

Please find the code below

````
lur6 <- lur6[,-1]
comp <- na.exclude(lur6)

set.seed(100)  
inTrain <- createDataPartition(y = comp$pm, 
                               p = 0.8, list = FALSE)
training <- comp[inTrain,]
testing <- comp[-inTrain,]
x_train <- training[,-1]
y_train <- training[,1]
x_test <- testing[,-1]
y_test <- testing[,1]

dtrain <- xgb.DMatrix(as.matrix(sapply(x_train,as.numeric)), label=y_train)
dtest <- xgb.DMatrix(as.matrix(sapply(x_test,as.numeric)), label=y_test)
dtest1 <- xgb.DMatrix(as.matrix(sapply(x_test,as.numeric)))

xgb_trcontrol = trainControl(
  method = "cv",
  number = 5,  
  allowParallel = TRUE,
  verboseIter = T,
  returnData = FALSE
)

xgbGrid <- expand.grid(nrounds = c(100,200,300,500),  
                       max_depth = c(5,10,20,30),
                       colsample_bytree = seq(0.75, 0.9,    length.out = 5),
                       eta = c(0.01,0.1,0.3),
                       gamma=0,
                       min_child_weight = c(1,3,5),
                       subsample = c(0.8,1)
)
 
set.seed(0) 
xgb_model = train(
  x_train, y_train,  
  trControl = xgb_trcontrol,
  tuneGrid = xgbGrid,
  method = "xgbTree"
)

xgb_model$bestTune                   
predicted = predict(xgb_model, x_test)
importance_matrix <- xgb.importance(names(x_train), model = xgb_model$finalModel)
xgb.plot.importance(importance_matrix)

pre <- fread("pred_tree_2.csv")
pred1 <- pre[,-c("ID")]
pred <- na.exclude(pred1)
x_pred <- xgb.DMatrix(as.matrix(sapply(pred,as.numeric)))

predict_var = predict(xgb_model$finalModel, x_pred)```

                    
Any suggestions on how to fix this is welcome!
````

Comment: did you try "predict_var = predict(xgb_model$finalModel, x_pred)"?

Comment: @RicardoVillalba Yes I did. Still got the error